# Why is my has_one database relationship not working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a relationship model in which students and employers can enter into a relationship when applying to a project.   Here are the models:

```
class Student < User
    has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :employers, through: :relationships
end

class Employer < User
    has_many :projects
    has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :project
    belongs_to :employer
    belongs_to :student

    validates_uniqueness_of :project_id, :scope => [:employer_id, :student_id]
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employer
end
```

State is a column in the projects table that is automatically set equal to 'posting'.  I am trying to show all relationships that have a project with state == :posting.  Here is my view code:

```
<% @relationships.each do |relationship| %>
        <% if relationship.project.state == :posting %>
            <%= relationship.project.inspect %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, in the controller for this view is:

```
@relationships = Relationship.all
```

When i try to open the view, i get:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column projects.relationship_id does not exist
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that I am not looking in the projects table for a relationship_id column.  My code should find the project from the relationship and then find the state column.  I have relationships has_one :project but i don't have :projects belongs_to relationships because a project does not need a relationship in order to exist.  I'm pretty sure my database relations are right.  How do I fix my view code?  Or, if my db relationships are wrong, what's wrong?

Update
i forgot to mention that Employer and Student are both User models through polymorphic association.  The user model has a type column that can be either Student or Employer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare that `Relationship` `has_one :project`, you are telling Rails that the `Project` model (and the corresponding `projects` database table) has a `relationship_id` field . When you refer to `relationship.project` in your view, you cause that table/field to be referenced, resulting in your error.

Given that each relationship should indeed have just one project associated with it, you should declare `Project` as `belongs_to :relationship`, create the appropriate migration and update your code accordingly to maintain the value of this field.

Comment: Hmm, the problem with that though is that there are many relationships that can each have the same project.

Comment: Then your relationship should `belongs_to :project` and your project should `has_many :relationships`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems like it should be

```
class Employer < User
  has_many :projects, through: :relationships
```

for this to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned.  Employer and Student are both User models through polymorphic association.  The user model has a type column that can be either Student or Employer.  I will add this to the question content.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, an employer has a project regardless of whether or not there is a relationship.  An employer can create a project.  There is no relationship until a student applies to the project.